# Why won't electron app wont run after it was packaged

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

I was able to successfully package my app to Windows, but when I run it, I get the message "**This app can't run on your PC**", please help!

```js
{
  "name": "window",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"init\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: see [windowsrepost/app-cant-run-windows-10](https://windowsreport.com/app-cant-run-windows-10/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20seeing%20This,bit%20version%20of%20Windows%2010.&text=Another%20solution%20is%20to%20switch,bit%20version%20of%20Windows%2010.)

Comment: I have a 64 bit version of windows so that doesn't solve the issue.